# Identifier is not CLS-compliant error when using Agile.net code protector

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I'm currently in the process of protecting my software using [Agile.net obfuscator](http://secureteam.net/Obfuscator.aspx)

I'd like to obfuscate all symbols in my application using unprintable naming scheme. After I protect my software I get 'Identifier is not CLS-compliant' exception when loading the application.

Has anyone came across a similar issue using Agile.net? I can reproduce the problem by only using 'renaming' option, leaving all other protection options disabled.

Any help will be appreciated.